# Accessing derived class-only methods using base class object

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I am new to OO programming and I was wondering how to solve the following question -

I have the following:

```
class A
{
    public:
    A() {};
    ~A() {};

    virtual functionA() = 0;
}

class B: public A
{
    public:
    B() {};
    ~B() {};

    functionA();
    functionB();
}
```

Is there a way to access functionB using an object of the base class A? If no, why is it not possible? If yes, how does one do it? I tried to find this answer on this site but I didn't find anything concrete.

Comment: If `functionB` accesses some member of `B`, how do you expect the program to work if you access `functionB` through an object of type `A`?

Comment: Please define what is "access functionB". Get its address, call it, something else?

Comment: By "access functionB", I mean "call functionB"

Comment: @xskxzr What if functionB doesn't access some member of B? For example suppose functionB accepts some arguments and works only with them. What then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify your example slightly to give you a better understanding:

```
class Animal
{
    public:
    A() {};
    ~A() {};

    virtual Eat() = 0;
}

class Bird: public Animal
{
    public:
    B() {};
    ~B() {};

    Eat();
    Fly();
}
```

Should an `Animal` object be allowed to access the function `Fly` which belongs to `Bird` ?
No, because **not all** `Animal`s are `Bird`s. 
But if you are sure than a specific `Animal` object is a `Bird`, then you can downcast the `Animal` object to `Bird` and then call `Fly` function.
However, this is not generally recommended. Upcasts (casting `Bird` to `Animal`) are okay because all `Bird`s are `Animal`s.

Answer (score 1):

In general this is not possible.  Class A can't access derived methods in Class B.  The general relationship is upward for inheritance. Imagine a Class C that also has functionB, the resolution would be ambiguous.

```
class A
{
}

class B:public A
{
   void functionB() {};
}

class C:public A
{
   void functionB() {}
}


main()
{
  A a;
  a.functionB();  // What to call here?
}
```

With that being said, if an instance is in fact a B then a downcast could be used.

```
main()
{
  B b;
  A&a = b; // ok since a B is-a A
  auto & b1 = dynamic_cast<B&>(a);  // ok since this particular instance is-a B
  b1.functionB();
}
```

perhaps this is what you were reaching for.

Comment: If you use dynamic_cast, you should do it in a way that allows you to verify if it was successful or not.  If doing it with pointers, you can check if it is nullptr (incompatible types).  But with reference, you cannot and it's UB.

Answer (score 1):

You can access only virtual method of B using the object A. This is called **runtime-polymorphism** and it is achieved with virtual function. Hence in order to implement the runtime behaviour C++ compiler inserts Virtual Table for every class having virtual function or class inherited from the class that has virtual function.

As in your code, i will make small modification:-

```
class A
{
    public:
    A() {};
    ~A() {};

    virtual void functionA() = 0;
    virtual void functionC();
}

class B: public A
{
    public:
    B() {};
    ~B() {};

    void functionA() override; //  C++ 11 : override keyword ensures that the function is virtual and is overriding a virtual function from a base class.
    void functionB();
}
```

As the class A contains a virtual function C++ compiler inserts a pointer v_ptr called as virtual table pointer. Compiler also creates a table for that class called as virtual table known as vtable for the class. The table is created compile time v_ptr holds the address of v_table of the corresponding class. vtable is a array of function pointers pointing to virtual function. As functionA is pure virtual so in vtable the address entry for functionA will be null and but functionC has a valid address entry in vtable as it is not pure virtual function.

virtual table contains pointers to functionA() and functionC function of A class. But the implementation is incomplete as functionA is pure virtual. So you can't create object of class A.

As B Class inherits from A class, and as we know A class has a data member v_ptr. B class inherits v_ptr of A class but new virtual table will be created compile time for B class. Hence v_ptr of B class holds the address of vtable of B class. As B class has implemented functionA function. vtable of B class contains pointer to functionA function of B class but pointer to functionC function of base class i.e A class.

```
A *a = new B();
a->functionA(); //calls B functionA
a->functionC(); //calls A functionC since we haven't overriden this function in B
```